# JSON error using twitteR caused by RCurl proxy

Tags: json, r, twitter, rcurl, twitter-r

I am trying to use twitteR's `searchTwitter()` function with a curl proxy, but I'm getting a JSON-related error.  I see that a lot of people have gotten this same JSON error.  But I believe the cause of mine is different, so I will try to be specific in my question.

I have properly set up the OAuth connection with Twitter's API. I am on Windows, and using the latest version of R and all the packages. I am using a proxy because of my company's firewall. I am using `RCurlOptions` to configure the proxy.  I also bring in RJSONIO. The code runs fine outside of my company's firewall when I don't have to  configure the proxy.

```
library(RCurl)
library(twitteR)
library(RJSONIO)

options(RCurlOptions = list(
    proxy ="proxy.mycompany.net:8080",
    proxyuserpwd="USERNAME:PASSWORD",
    cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

load("OAuth.RData") #Load in my OAuth credentials object
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)

geico.tweets <- searchTwitter('@geico', n = 2)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in twFromJSON(out) : 
  Error: Malformed response from server, was not JSON.
```

I know it is not an issue of Twitter returning a character that can't be properly parsed by R, because I can't even bring in any single tweet (plus, it works fine outside the firewall).

This link suggests it may be caused by my use of RCurl: https://github.com/omegahat/RCurl/issues/1

His explanation is the JSON is messed up because of my use of RCurl.  The `\\` is converted to `\` by `R_mapString`, which is called only if the data includes Unicode character.  That's about as much as I understand.  He also mentions a `.mapUnicode` argument.

Is there some parameter in `RCurlOptions` I can configure that will fix this issue? Thanks.